# Is there any minimal operating system to run virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, operating-systems

I would like to use a OS X in a virtual machine, the problem is running the VM in Windows or Ubuntu because the host OS takes a lot of CPU.

Is there any very minimal operating system that can virtualize OS X and that can use VMWare files? A key criteria is that the host OS would allow most of the CPU power to be used in the guest OS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to also be able to use the host, a lite install of Linux would work (such as [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)).  If you don't plan on using the host, check out VMWare's [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in fact no, i don't need to use the host, i would like to give most of my cpu to the guest

Comment: I saw VMWare didn't have OSX support, have they added it? i had to patch my windows vmware in order to run OSX

Comment: If you're looking to run 100% OSx, you would need Apple hardware.  If you're looking to run OSx86 (http://www.osx86project.org/), VMWare/VirtualBox/etc can handle it.

Comment: No, i run Hackintosh, and my vmware supports it but i had to patch it in order to use OSX

Comment: Sorry, haven't played around with Hackintosh before.

Comment: @Harlandraka you can't emulate MAC OSX on NON-MAC hardware; it's illegal.

Comment: @AndreaCi Yes, ok, i don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building (installing) Gentoo on the host because it can be made very minimal and optimized for the host. Having support for VMWare products in the package repository is also a major plus.